# Twisted reactor starting multiple times in a single program?

Tags: python, twisted, reactor

Is it possible to start the reactor more than once in the same program? Suppose you wanted to encapsulate twisted functionality inside a method, for API purposes.

For example, mymodule.py looks like this:

```
  1 from twisted.web.client import getPage
  2 from twisted.internet import reactor
  3 
  4 def _result(r):
  5     print r
  6     reactor.stop()
  7 
  8 def _error(e):
  9     print e
 10     reactor.stop()
 11 
 12 def getGoogle():
 13     d = getPage('http://www.google.com')
 14     d.addCallbacks(_result, _error)
 15     reactor.run()
 16 
 17 def getYahoo():
 18     d = getPage('http://www.yahoo.com')
 19     d.addCallbacks(_result, _error)
 20     reactor.run()
 21
```

main.py looks like this:

```
  1 import mymodule
  2 
  3 getGoogle()
  4 getYahoo()
```

Comment: Even if it works, I would advice against it. It's messy. You should first attach all your handlers and tasks, and then run the reactor.

Comment: I think the requirements for the task run against the grain of twisted, from what I understand. Basically the task is to create an API so the user needs to know nothing about twisted. Note, main.py, It's synchronous. Alternatively, mymodule.py isn't. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's another way to organize your code, exploiting the single-threaded nature of Twisted: queue up all the urls you want to process, kick off the reactor, and decrement a counter when each request completes.  When the counter reaches zero, stop the reactor which will return the results:

```
from twisted.web.client import getPage
from twisted.internet import reactor

class Getter(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._sequence = 0
        self._results = []
        self._errors = []

    def add(self, url):
        d = getPage(url)
        d.addCallbacks(self._on_success, self._on_error)
        d.addCallback(self._on_finish)
        self._sequence += 1

    def _on_finish(self, *narg):
        self._sequence -= 1
        if not self._sequence:
            reactor.stop()

    _on_success = lambda self, *res: self._results.append(res)
    _on_error = lambda self, *err: self._errors.append(err)

    def run(self):
        reactor.run()
        return self._results, self._errors

g = Getter()
for url in ('http://www.google.com', 'http://www.yahoo.com', 'idontexist'):
    g.add(url)
results, errors = g.run()
print results
print errors
```

Comment: I like your implementation. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

A more straightforward solution, which doesn't require you to manage a counter:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
from twisted.web.client import getPage

def printPage(page):
    print page

def printError(err):
    print err

urls = ['http://www.google.com',
        'http://www.example.com']

jobs = []
for url in urls:
    jobs.append(getPage(url).addCallbacks(printPage,
                                          printError))

def done(ignored):
    reactor.stop()
defer.gatherResults(jobs).addCallback(done)

reactor.run()
```

You should take a look [here](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/10.2.0/api/twisted.internet.defer.html) at what's provided by the deferred API because it will save you a lot of time and make your code easier to debug.